# Ionic view and facebook login using firebase doesn't work

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, ionic-framework, firebase

I create a application with ionic and firebase V3, and I add a facebook authentification. On my browser everything is ok, I'm able to login with a redirect on facebook, but when I try with "Ionic View" app on IOS, when I pressed button "login with facebook" nothing happened.

here is my controller.js for the connexion :

```
.controller('WelcomeCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
   $scope.facebook = function(){
      var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
      provider.addScope('user_friends');
      provider.addScope('email');
      provider.addScope('read_custom_friendlists');
      firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function(result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        result.user.accessToken = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
        console.log(user);
        $state.go('tab.home');
      }).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        var email = error.email;
        var credential = error.credential;
      });
   }
})
```

Here is my view 'welcome.html' :

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="connexion-system">
        <img src="img/bglogin.png">
        <div class="buttons">
            <a href="#/login"><button class="button button-block button-assertive"> Connexion </button></a>
            <a href="#/signin"><button class="button button-block button-energized"> Inscription </button></a>
            <a ng-click="facebook()"><button class="button button-block button-custom"> Facebook login </button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="img/logo.svg" class="logo-login">
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I have had this issue, I believe Ionic does not like `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)`. Might want to research another option.

Comment: Would you have an other solution ? SignInWithPopUp doesn't work too ..

Comment: Does someone have a solution ?